# Rounding a number in google sheets using gspread API

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets, gspread

I am writing a pandas dataframe to google sheets using gspread:

```
from gspread_formatting import *
import gspread
from df2gspread import df2gspread as d2g
import pandas as pd

d2g.upload(data, sheet.id, 'test_name', clean=True, credentials=creds, col_names=True, row_names=False)
```

While the pandas dataframe is rounded to `2` decimal points the value in google sheets sometimes have more than that.

`df`

```
a               b
100.56          600.79
```

Result in google sheets:

```
aa                b
100.5616          600.79
```

And I can't find any information how I can round a value using python gspread API.

Comment: you cannot round the values using python gspread API, but you can do it beforehand. Actually, I think the safe way to achieve what you need is to convert your data to formatted string with two decimal places, and send string values to gspread.

Comment: I am rounding every value to 2 decimal points in my df, before pushing it to google sheets, but I had to modify the `d2g` library to be able to push `int` values rather than `str`

Comment: can you set the ValueInputOption to USER_ENTERED somewhere? https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueInputOption

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you get the worksheet element you can use format to achieve what you want.

```
sh = gc.open("sheet_name")
worksheet = sh.get_worksheet(0) # your sheet number
worksheet.format('A', {'numberFormat': {'type' : 'NUMBER', 'pattern': '0.0#'}})
```